# fish: check if running in venv

Tags: python-venv, fish

How do I know if I'm running in a venv in fish?

I want to have the following in my `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```
if status is-interactive
  cd $HOME/d/
end
```

but I don't want it to `cd` when I run `pipenv shell`

```
# does something like this exist ...?
if status is-interactive and not is-venv
  cd $HOME/d/
end
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it messes me up". What happens that surprised you? What did you expect? What version of Fish and the `pipenv` command are you using? If the `pipenv` is creating a new interactive Fish shell, and you don't want it to `cd`, then you should use a different test, or eliminate that code completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [set](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html) seems to work:

```
if status is-interactive; and not set -q VIRTUAL_ENV
  cd $HOME/d/
end
```

Thanks faho! very helpful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `and` is a new command, so you need to add a semicolon before it: `if status is-interactive; and not set -q VIRTUAL_ENV`. Or, in fish >= 3.0 use `&&`: `if status is-interactive && not set -q VIRTUAL_ENV`.

Comment: That means your "working" check is faulty - it checks if any of the variables `$VIRTUAL_ENV`, `$and`, `$status` and `$is-interactive` (which isn't a valid variable name) is set. It never checks if it's interactive.

Comment: Your edit fixes the situation for the workiing check, but the non-working one fails for the same reason - no semicolon before the `and`. That is what breaks it.